# Getting complete history of an SVN repo that's been renamed using git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have an SVN repository which was renamed from "Project" to "Project v1".

I then did a `git svn clone` to create a git version of the renamed SVN folder.

When I `git log` the newly created git repository, I only see a single history item. It's the commit message which I gave the SVN repository when I renamed the folder.

Is there a way for the git repository to have all of the SVN history prior to the folder being renamed (or any other possible renames prior to that one)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I have done this in the past (not knowing it's the best or only way!) was to explicitly `git svn fetch` the prior history (you may need a second remote for this) and then graft the renamed tree onto the old history with `git filter-branch` (there's a specific example in the docs for reparenting a tree).

### Example

From: `svn://server/repo/project`
To:`svn://server/repo/project_v1`

Optional first step:  If you have no existing `git-svn` repo for this, go ahead and `git svn clone svn://server/repo/project`.  Most people will probably already have this repo around because they have been working with `git-svn` all along.  If you have no git repo at all yet you can do the initial clone on either side.

In your `git-svn` repo add a remote for the new name of the project.  I don't think there's a command for this, you just add a stanza to your `.git/config` very similar to the one that's already there:

```
[svn-remote "svn_v1"]
        url = svn://server/repo/project_v1
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-v1
```

That new SVN remote can be selected with the `--remote svn_v1` option to any `git-svn` command.  The first thing you'll want to do is `git-svn fetch --remote svn_v1` which will populate your git repo with the history of that copy.  As the original question notes, this will be a very brief history!

Now we apply the example in the `git filter-branch` manpage.  You will need to know the tip of the old history, which is `git show-ref -s remotes/git-svn` (again, assuming your original clone was the old version).  Then use `git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p <graft-id>/"' remotes/git-svn-v1` where `<graft-id>` is the SHA you just got for the tip of the old history.

Verify that this worked with `git log remotes/git-svn-v1` and see all the history.

At this point you can go to your working branch and `git reset --hard remotes/git-svn-v1` to switch that branch over to the new history.

**Note that the `svn-remote` named "svn" will be your default, so at the end you will want to rename the remotes in the `[svn-remote "..."]` lines in your `.git/config` so that your primary one is named "svn".  You can name the other one `-old` or even remote it.**

*Caveat:  This is from memory and I have not just repeated these steps myself.  Comments and corrections welcome.*

Comment: Could you please, please, please, give some more specific details on how to do this?

Comment: @BenJackson Hope you can help. When running `git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p bc1acd15c431afb3d63ed70870df2ee327acc816/"' remotes/git-svn-v1` returns: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'bc1acd15c431afb3d63ed70870df2ee327acc816/': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Then: `git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p bc1acd15c431afb3d63ed70870df2ee327acc816"' remotes/git-svn-v1` returns: `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated 's' command`

Comment: @BenJackson : For an answer this old and, as you stated, "just" from memory, it worked astonishingly well. You just saved my day, your solution worked perfectly well with git-2.15.0 in cygwin!

Comment: @IQn I got the same error when trying to run this command in the Git bash in Windows. I had to switch quotes and double quotes and remove the escape character. The following command worked for me: `git filter-branch --parent-filter "sed 's/^$/-p bc1acd15c431afb3d63ed70870df2ee327acc816/'" remotes/git-svn-v1`